# In this case synonyms

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

Is there any similar words/phrases with the same meaning that I can use in my sentences in order to avoid tautology. Except **in this example.**

I would be grateful for any variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In this instance
- Under these circumstances
- In this situation
- With respect to
- In the event of
- Here